# Apache2 mod_rewrite difficulty with GET variables

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, webserver

On the website.conf file I have:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /srv/http/website/cgi-bin
    ServerName website
    ServerAlias www.website

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^$ ""
    RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)$ /?tab=repo

...
```

My goal is to have http://localhost/ redirect to localhost and http://localhost/word redirect to http://localhost/?tab=word.
With the current directives I get a 404 error, because it's trying to open the file repo @ DocumentRoot. All I need is to rewrite the URL to make the word be a GET variable.

A directive like the following works:

```
RewriteRule /word$ http://localhost/?tab=word
```

This is obviously somewhat simplistic because I would then have to do it for every possibility.

I experimented with those directives on this website https://htaccess.madewithlove.com/, that I found from another thread on SO, the results are what I expect them to be, I.E.: http://localhost/word is transformed to http://localhost/?tab=word.

Extra info: The website does not have any PHP.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> # Virtual Host
> RewriteRule ^$ ""
> RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)$ /?tab=repo
> ```
>
> A directive like the following works:
>
> ```
> RewriteRule /word$ http://localhost/?tab=word
> ```

The difference with the "working directive" is that you've included a slash prefix. The regex `^([a-z]+)$` does not allow for a slash prefix, so never matches.

You are also failing to use the captured backreference (ie. `$1`) in the *substitution* string, so it would always rewrite to `/?tab=repo` regardless of the URL requested.

Consequently, the first rule, that matches against `^$` will never match either - but this rule is not required. You are not performing a redirect when requesting the root - you just don't want to do anything and instead allow mod_dir to serve the directory index.

In a virtualhost context the URL-path matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern* is a root-relative URL-path, starting with a slash.

So, your rule(s) should be like this instead:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/([a-z]+)$ /?tab=$1 [L]
```

(Or, make the slash prefix *optional*, ie. `^/?([a-z]+)$`)

However, `/?tab=<word>` is not strictly a valid end-point. What is the actual file that is handling the request? This should be included in the rewrite (and not rely on the `DirectoryIndex`). You state you are not using PHP, so how are you reading the URL parameter?

> I experimented with those directives on this website `https://htaccess.madewithlove.com/`,

You are not using `.htaccess` in your example. mod_rewrite behaves slightly differently depending on context (`.htaccess`, *directory*, *virtualhost* and *server*).

---

*Reference:*

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule

> **What is matched?**
>
> In VirtualHost context, The Pattern will initially be matched against
> the part of the URL after the hostname and port, and before the query
> string (e.g. "/app1/index.html"). This is the (%-decoded) URL-path.
>
> In per-directory context (Directory and .htaccess), the Pattern is
> matched against only a partial path, for example a request of
> "/app1/index.html" may result in comparison against "app1/index.html"
> or "index.html" depending on where the RewriteRule is defined.

Comment: I replied to my post with some more details and info so that the code would be formatted, thank you btw

Answer (score 0):

After tinkering a bit more I got down to this:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME} [PT,L] 

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME} [PT,L] 

RewriteRule ^/([^index.cgi]{1}.+)$ /index.cgi?tab=$1 [L]
```

It opens files if they exist and sends requests that don't exist to my C++ cgicc program. The only thing I don't understand is why the `-d` condition  isn't opening directories the same way the `-f` one opens files.